# Is there an Eclipse plugin for collaborative editing?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, collaboration

I setup etherpad and showed my co-worker, and he swears there is an Eclipse plugin that does the same thing but can not remember the name. Neither of us use Eclipse regularly except if we were both interested in making the switch.

Comment: Eclipse Che is another possibility: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_Che

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin

This is the current "official" solution to collaborative editing in Eclipse.

Comment: The Wiki seems very outdated, and I am have a lot of trouble installing with my current knowledge of plugins. Is there an up-to-date tutorial you know of?

Comment: I have been looking around for a new version or an alternative, but have not been able to find any. Sorry.

Comment: At least you try! You have my thanks

Comment: It seems that such a feature is suggested for eclipse che in the future -> https://github.com/eclipse/che/issues/8286

Answer (score 11):

Have a look into Saros project: http://www.saros-project.org/

Comment: A more recent Eclipse offering that my company makes - https://codetogether.com. Works across Eclipse, VS Code, IntelliJ, and even a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I think a similar project should exist based on the [framework ECF](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EUG:Overview).
([DocShare](http://wiki.eclipse.org/DocShare_Plugin) as [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9156970/6309) by [Tonny Madsen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/796559/tonny-madsen))

There was a SOC project for [real-time sharing named Cola](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RT_Shared_Editing), but I don't know its current status.

Comment: DocShare is based on / uses ECF, and is based on the Cola algorithm. (See link on other answer for details.