# Developing environment sync

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cloud

Is there any way to sync the code between two systems like cloud services(Google docs/Sky drive) in Eclipse/Android Studio IDE's ? Is there any plugin for eclipse to do this ? or Any other IDE which supports this ?

while searching i got something like [this](https://c9.io/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to sync code between different machines *asyncronously* then you only need to use a version control system.

If you want to edit the *exact same* document in eclipse with multiple people, then all answers are in [Is there an Eclipse plugin for collaborative editing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156449/is-there-an-eclipse-plugin-for-collaborative-editing).

Cloud9 is just for coding in the browser and storing the project in the cloud. You probably don't want that.